# How to get notification response from the APNS using C#

Tags: c#, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm creating one web api application, and I want to send notification to iOS devices.

I've tried with pushsharp, but it works fine with few devices only, while sending it to multiple devices with expired/invalid tokens its not sending notifications to all devices.

So, I'm going with following code:

```
public async Task pushMessage(string deviceToken, string message)
{
  int port = 2195;
  String hostname = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";

  String certificatePath = "~/test.p12" // my certificate path 

  X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(certificatePath), CommonSource.GetAppleCertificatePassword(), X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
  X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);

  TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
  SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null);
   try
  {
     sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, SslProtocols.Tls, false);
     MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
     BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
     writer.Write((byte)0);
     writer.Write((byte)0);
     writer.Write((byte)32);

     writer.Write(HexStringToByteArray(deviceToken.ToUpper()));    
     String payload = message.ToString(); 

     writer.Write((byte)0);
     writer.Write((byte)payload.Length);
     byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
     writer.Write(b1);
     writer.Flush();
     byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();
     sslStream.Write(array);
     sslStream.Flush();

     // Read message from the server. 
     //byte[] response = ReadMessage(sslStream);   

     client.Close();
   }
  catch (System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException ex)
  {
     LogError(ex.Message);
     client.Close();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    LogError(e.Message);
    client.Close();
   }            
}
```

This code works exactly what I wanted. 
But now I want to check response from APNS server. So I've checked with `byte[] response = ReadMessage(sslStream);`
And  ReadMessage method looks like:

```
private byte[] ReadMessage(SslStream sslStream)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    int bytes = -1;
    do
    {
        bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);

    } while (bytes != 0);

    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

But when I run this, it stuck at `bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);`
 I'm not able to figure out the issue.

Can anyone tell me, what is the issue with my code?

Comment: Attach OnNotificationFailed event handler to PushSharp object. 

It will get hit if notification fails and you can log the relevant error.

Comment: @Ajay: As I mentioned in the question, I'm not using PushSharp anyway in this question. My question is regarding getting response from apple server. Though I've tried with it to, it was giving me an error of invalid token and it has stopped queue.

Comment: @HinaKhuman Redownload your cetrificates and your cetrificates is not valid.i think,

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj: Yes I've already tried it too, but I received the same error.

Comment: @HinaKhuman.my Simple Answer is Your token is not valid from mobile client.use FCM For pushnotification.google have nice console to send push notification to the devices.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: also The device token relay on the installation of the app.

It means that if you reinstall the application, it changes; it doesn't metter if you do it from a backup, an iOS upgrade etc.,

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj: Thanks but that is not my question anyway, the current code is working fine. I just need to get response from APNS.

Answer (score 5):

According to this article

[The problem with Apples Push Notification Service… Solutions and Workarounds…](http://redth.codes/the-problem-with-apples-push-notification-ser/)

> 1. Apple never sends a response for messages that succeeded.
> 2. An error response may not immediately be returned before you have a chance to send more notifications to the stream, but before Apple closes the connection. These notifications that might still ‘make it through’ are left in limbo. They are never acknowledged or delivered, and never have error responses returned for them.

So in a case where your request works as intended there will be no response. That would mean that your attempt to read a response will not get anything and this is what you are experiencing when you can't get past the read line. It is waiting for a response that might never come.

Comment: Thanks, but apple office docs. stated something else, please see this from **HTTP/2 Response from APNs** https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH11-SW1

Comment: Any further explanation?

Comment: In your code you're using the legacy Binary Provider API and the link is for using the new HTTP/2 method to call APNs so the documentation is not relevant to your code